# How do I create a formula to insert a hyperlink if another field is marked true

Tags: formula-field

Below is my attempt at using a formula field to create a hyperlink if another cosum field is cheked tru:

```
IF (NICX__Property__r.SUE_Integrated__c = TRUE)
HYPERLINK("https://my.meetingbroker.com/SimpleUI/RFPDetails.aspx?RFPId="& NICX__ExternalId__c ,"MeetingBroker RFP")
)
```

I am getting a syntax error:

> Error: Syntax error. Extra HYPERLINK

Not sure where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT - Fixed Hyperlink Definition Error**

Your `IF` Syntax is wrong. Change it to this:

```
IF (
    NICX__Property__r.SUE_Integrated__c = TRUE,
    HYPERLINK(
        "https://my.meetingbroker.com/SimpleUI/RFPDetails.aspx?RFPId="& NICX__ExternalId__c, 
        "MeetingBroker RFP" ),
    ""
)
```

I've tested that this compiles for me.

Comment: Weird, I copied the above and now getting the error blow

Comment: Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'HYPERLINK()'. Expected 2, received 1

Comment: Oops - I  added that by mistake - I took out "MeetingBroker RFP" from the hyperlink definition and moved it into the IF statement. Fixed it now.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Not quite.  Getting the syntax error below:

Comment: Error: Syntax error. Missing "

Comment: I've fixed it. However, the purpose of the answer is not to give you the exact working code, but to give you a reason why your original answer isn't working. It's hard to run code examples to check if they are completely correct, so you have to expect (and be able to fix) things like this.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.  I will use your example to get a better understanding of formula expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fix your parentheses.

```
IF (
    NICX__Property__r.SUE_Integrated__c = TRUE,
    HYPERLINK("https://my.meetingbroker.com/SimpleUI/RFPDetails.aspx?RFPId=" &
        NICX__ExternalId__c,
    "MeetingBroker RFP"
)
```